# Opening file - Performing a function

Tags: python, file, wxpython

I was wondering if someone could give me a direction on how to give functions to a file... This is a bit hard to explain, so I'll try my best.
Let's say I have an application (using wxPython) and let's say that I have a file. Now this file is assigned to open with the application. So, I double-click the file and it opens the application. Now my question is, what would have to be written on the file to, for example, open up a dialog? So we double-click the file and it opens a dialog on the application?

PS: I know that I have first to associate the program with a certain file type to double-click it, but thats not the question.

Comment: so are you trying to have scripts that can be interpreted by your program to perform specific tasks?

Comment: Your question does not make any sense. Your application can to what ever with files associated with an application. Your application can read the passed filenames through sys.argv[] What else is needed here? If your application needs some hard-codes paths then the functionality is fully in the hand of your application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK most platforms just call the helper app with the file you clicked on as an argument, so your filepath will be in `sys.argv[1]`

Comment: Could you please elaborate on that?

Comment: On which part? As far as I know, when you double click on a file associated to run with another program, the other program is run with your file (What you clicked on) as an argument, like `python2.7 /full/path/to/your/file` thus, if you `import sys` and take a look at the `sys.argv` array, you should be able to find your file and operate on it from there.

Comment: @Richo So, are you suggesting that I add a line to my application such as `if sys.argv[1] == filepath: do something?`

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're trying to do, I can help you understand how things work but without more information I can't tell you how to achieve your specific goal. Yes, you can use that to test the filename your script was called with.

Comment: @Richo Essentially, I'm just trying to do something on the application as I open it with a file. So I have a file that contains information, and lets say that in this example, it only has text: `Hello`. So, as I open it, it opens the application and pops a Message Box with the `Hello` from the file.

Comment: `WhateverYourMessageBoxFunctionIs(open(sys.argv[1], 'r').read())` This is an overly simple example with essentially no error checking and obviously you'll need to replace that function with something that creates a message box..

Answer (score 1):

I think what he wants to do is associate a file extension to his application so when he opens the file by double clicking it, it sends the contents of the file to his app; in this case, display the contents within a Dialog?

If this is the case, than the first thing you would need to do (provided you are on windows) is create the appropriate file association for your file extention. This can be done through the registry and when setup correctly will open your app with the the path/filename of the file that was executed as the first argument. Ideally it is the same as executing it from the command line like:

**C:\your\application.exe "C:\The\Path\To\my.file"**

Now as suggested above, you would then need to use sys.argv to to obtain the arguments passed to your application, in this case **C:\Path\To\my.file** would be the first argument. Simply put, sys.argv is a list of arguments passed to the application; in this case the first entry ***sys.argv[0]*** will always be the path to your application, and as mentioned above, **sys.argv[1]** would be the path to your custom file.

Example:

```
import sys

myFile = sys.argv[1]
f = file(myFile, "r")
contents = f.read()
f.close()
```

Then you will be able to pass the variable ***contents*** to your dialog to do whatever with.

Comment: Yes, I know that I do have to put some file association on registry, and I've been thinking about this... I mean when you open a file with an application, as far as I've seen, it just launches the application, even if it's already open... How can I prevent this from happening and instead of opening a new process, just be able to pass the information to the running process? Hope this makes sense haha.

Comment: honestly, I have never looked into it that far. This [link](http://wxpython-users.1045709.n5.nabble.com/How-to-test-if-app-already-loaded-td2352208.html) should give you some of the information needed, it explains how to avoid opening multiple instances of your application, what it does not touch up on is how to send the value of sys.argv[1] to the frame after it detects there is already an instance of the app opened.